# How can I track a "most wins" leaderboard using the Buddy API?

Tags: leaderboards

I work on a mobile game with leaderboards that rank players by most wins. Currently, we've rolled our own, but I am looking to replace this with a SaaS leaderboard solution offering rolling time-based leaderboards (e.g. most wins this week, most wins in the last 30 days, etc.).

One of the leaderboard services I am looking at, [Buddy](http://buddy.com/), seems to provide "top score" leaderboards, which is not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm trying to register wins for players with the service and produces a leaderboard by summing the wins for each player for the time period I'm interested in.

How can I accomplish this with Buddy?

Comment: Is your question really about polling for leaderboard services (which is off-topic), or is really about how to track the "most wins" using app4 or Buddy's service (which is on topic)?

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify that it is about doing most wins on Buddy or app42.

Comment: Those are probably two different questions with two different answers, depending on the APIs. I arbitrarily edited the question to focus only Buddy, and removed the bits that were suggesting a "which tech to use" question.